# ASP.NET MVC CORE Reflection Adding Services Problem

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I using MVC Core 2.1

I have some projects that all of my projects has static class & method for add services like this:

```
[AutoServiceCollection]
    public static class ModuleServices
    {
        public static void Run(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<ILanguagesDA, LanguagesDA>();
        }
    }
```

Now i want run all of **ModuleServices.Run** methods by reflection like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection addModuleServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var assemblies = AssemblyTools.AssemblyLocator.GetAssemblies();
            foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var cls in assembly.GetTypes())
                    {
                        var attr = cls.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                            x.AttributeType.Name == typeof(AutoServiceCollectionAttribute).Name);
                        if (attr != null)
                        {
                            var mi = cls.GetMethod("Run");
                            if (mi != null)
                            {
                                mi.Invoke(null, new object[] {services});
                            }

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }

            return services;
        }
```

And add addModuleServices method to startup.cs file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddMvc();

      //add modules services
      services.addModuleServices();
}
```

After add all of services to IServiceCollection by reflection,

I want to get service like this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IServiceProvider _provider;

        public HomeController(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            _provider = provider;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var langDA = (ILanguagesDA) _provider.GetService(typeof(ILanguagesDA));
        }
    }
```

But problem is
**langDA** variable is not filled and throw this exception

```
'langDA' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    FileName: null
    FusionLog: null
    HResult: -2147024894
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Cannot load assembly 'D:\\Projects\\FrameworkCore\\FrameworkCore\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\Sp.Base.dll'."
    Source: "0601e19325e244618b145b4d25ec19dc"
    StackTrace: "   at <>x.<>m0(HomeController <>4__this)"
    TargetSite: {Sp.Base.DataAccess.Interfaces.ILanguagesDA <>m0(FrameworkCore.Controllers.HomeController)}
```

But this problem is just for reflection adding and if i add service directly by extension method to IServiceCollecion, this work correctly!!

Why this problem is occurred and how can resolve it (i must use reflection)?

**[SOLVED]**

I used this code to get list of all assemblies:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);    
foreach (string dll in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll"))
{
   allAssemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(dll));
}
```

and changing that to this code:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);    
foreach (string dll in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll"))
{
   allAssemblies.Add(AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(dll));
}
```

and now that's work fine :)

Comment: You should not inject `IServiceProvider` into your classes. This is an anti-pattern called pService Locator](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). You should inject `ILanguagesDA` directly into the constructor.

Comment: ok, i refactor my code but the new exception thrown `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Sp.Base.DataAccess.Interfaces.ILanguagesDA' while attempting to activate 'FrameworkCore.Controllers.HomeController'` because the problem is another thing

Comment: After inspecting your code, I have to conclude that your question does not have the proper information that allows anyone else but you to see what the problem is. You should [debug your code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to find the problem.

Comment: What is `AssemblyTools.AssemblyLocator.GetAssemblies();`? What is the code for `ILanguagesDA` and `LanguagesDA`. Fail to reproduce your issue with `public class LanguagesDA: ILanguagesDA   {    }    public interface 
 LanguagesDA   {    }` and `var assembly = typeof(Startup).Assembly;`

Comment: This is a brilliant architecture, well done! :-)